# Distinct Count in lambda expression giving one extra count

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get distinct count of values from a column 
Below is the code I am using

```
int NewDivision = dt
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(i => i.Field<string>("ParentName"))
  .Distinct()
  .Count();
```

dt is a DataTable here and it has 9 distinct values in it , but it shows count as 10 
I have checked the data manually by importing it into Excel sheet , Take a look here 
[image]

Is it also counting blank as a value ?

Additionally when I select only Blank , there is not a single row in data

Comment: Could you, please, *print out* these `10` distinct values? `string report = string.Join(", ", dt.AsEnumerable().Select(i => i.Field<string>("ParentName")).Distinct()); Console.Write(report);` Just carry out this easy experiment and you'll see what's actually going on.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko it shows String.Join has some invalid arguments

Comment: I think the blank row is occurring because of the header row. Suspect you are using the wrong option when importing the datatable. The excel worksheet doesn't have a header and you selected that it does.

Comment: Isn't it just the empty string being the 10th value?

Comment: @Saurabh: It seems we have different C# versions; let's try *materializing* `string report = string.Join(", ", ... .Distinct().ToArray());` - `.ToArray()` added

Comment: @DmitryBychenko , Thanks , I checked the required parameters and added .ToArray() already

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I tried your way and found that there are one value appear twice , once in caps 'MADHYA PRADESH' and once in normal 'Madhya Pradesh', Can we convert all in UPPERCASE and then apply distinct count ? is it possible in lambda expression ?

Comment: The code that you showed does what you're expecting it to do. You're not showing us what data you are providing it. As @DmitryBychenko said, look at the data.

Comment: @krillgar I hope you read the comment just before your comment , and its mine comment with more description

Comment: @Saurabh I hope you realize that comments aren't for information. They can (and occasionally do) get cleaned up. Questions on Stack Overflow are not for only yourself today. They remain here for everyone to help others who have similar problems. The way that your question is presented does not have any information about **why** your code doesn't do what you want it to do. As I said, the code you showed looks like it would work. Any reason that it "doesn't work" needs to be in there.

Comment: @krillgar Agree with you and I apologize for the same  , But Ofir Winegarten got it in first try with the same amount of information. Every person have different prospective , will try to include more details from now on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem is the case then you can use `Distinct` with `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`:

```
int NewDivision = dt
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(i => i.Field<string>("ParentName"))
  .Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
  .Count();
```